# What is the Ancient Egyptian word for "Fisher"

Tags: ancient-egypt, egypt

Or, failing that, "Fish". Need it for a project but really struggling to find anything definitive online. Thank you!

Comment: [Fishers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_(animal)) are native to northern North America, so it's unlikely that the ancient Egyptians would have encountered them.

Answer (score 2):

[Hieroglyphs.net](http://hieroglyphs.net/cgi/dictionary_lookup_free.pl) is a two-way online English to Hieroglyphs translation dictionary.

It gives translations of:

- **fish**:

  [image]
- **fisherman**:

  [image]

When I requested a translation for *fisher* it gave me only the result above for *fisherman*.

Preserving the comment below by [sempaiscuba♦](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/24858/sempaiscuba):

> If you're interested, Paul Dickson's [Dictionary of Middle Egyptian](https://www.pyramidtextsonline.com/documents/DicksonDictionary.pdf) is available online as a searchable pdf file. There are multiple options for fish /fisherman depending on context. Of course, the Old- and Late-Egyptian languages have other variants, but that kind of thing happens when your civilisation lasts more than three millennia!

Comment: If you're interested, Paul Dickson's [Dictionary of Middle Egyptian](https://www.pyramidtextsonline.com/documents/DicksonDictionary.pdf) is available online as a searchable pdf file.  There are multiple options for fish /fisherman depending on context.  Of course, the Old- and Late-Egyptian languages have other variants, but that kind of thing happens when your civilisation lasts more than three millennia!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to search up the dictionary too - much appreciated! :D